# unable to dequeue a cell with identifier during segue

Tags: swift, xcode, segue

I'm performing a segue when a button is pressed inside a cell of a table. I have the following code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == self.selectedFriends.count {
        tableView.register(AddFriendsCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "AddFriendsCell")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddFriendsCell", for: indexPath) as! AddFriendsCell
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = colourBrandBrown
        cell.testButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FriendsVC.segueTest), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    ...
```

The "segueTest" code is:

```
func segueTest() {

    print("TEST")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "addFriends", sender: self)

}
```

When I press the button, I get this result:

```
TEST
unable to dequeue a cell with identifier AddFriendsCell -
must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

You can see in the code that the AddFriendsCell is registered, so why is this error occuring?

Comment: Does AddFriendsCell have an associated xib file? If so, make you use the correct register method.

`func register(UINib?, forCellReuseIdentifier: String)`

Comment: I cannot see any .xib files in my project. I have infact tried this code earlier and it didn't work

Comment: The problem is in the class where the segue is going. Are you loading another tableview controller in the storyboard? I'm assuming you are and that tableviewcontroller has no prototype cells in it

Comment: You shouldn't be registering the identifier in `cellForRowAt`. If you're really using a programmatically created cell, you should register that class in `viewDidLoad` (or equivalent). But, are you really creating this cell programmatically (no NIB, no cell prototype in the storyboard)?!?

Comment: BTW, if you're getting this error _after_ you tap the button in the cell (which is well after `cellForRowAt` was called), then the problem is not with that cell, but rather in the next view controller to which you're transitioning. That must have a table view, itself...

Comment: I originally used the storyBoard to create the cell, however I then went over it problematically. The view controller that is being segued to is almost identical to the one that it is being segued from. I've just changed the view controller which it is getting segued to, with no errors. @Devster101 and Rob were correct in their assumptions, cheers